# How to delete a specific array item from PHP session

Tags: php

Im trying to delete an item from a session shopping cart. I used unset(), but somehow it didn't work

**Link**

```
<td width="100"><a href="?id=<?php echo $ids;?>&action=delete">
  <?php echo $ids;?></a></td>
```

**Unset**

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])&&($_GET['action']=="delete"))
{
    $new_id=$_GET['id'];
    unset($_SESSION['items'][$new_id]);
}
```

Comment: **A:** make sure you're calling `session_start()` before you try and unset the session var. **B:** ensure that the structure of your session data matches what you're trying to unset, and debug the `$_GET['id']` variable you're trying to use.

Comment: Try forcing the session updates to be committed using `session_write_close();`.

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure the `id` you are passing as a `get` parameter is set properly, and analyse the structure of your session variable with a `var_dump($_SESSION['items'])`, you should make sure it matches and comment your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

unset session ok look this code  result  `array(1) { ["id"]=> int(10) }`

```
 <?php
  $_SESSION['items']=
  array(
  "id"=>10,
  "new_id"=>6
  );
    unset($_SESSION['items']["new_id"]);
    var_dump($_SESSION['items']);
?>
```

Comment: the first nesting level of his array is a variable integer, not a static *string* like "new_id". how do you delete different cart item?